# Ruby substring from a file

Tags: ruby, substring

If I need to get a word from a text file, for example, I have this text file

```
 AWD,SUV,0km,auto
```

and I need to get the km number or the Drivetrain which is AWD, what do we do after reading the file?

here's how I'm reading the file

```
 def getWord(fileName)
file=fileName
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
  puts line

end
```

Comment: what result of puts line?

Comment: the text in the file @dedypuji

Comment: What are the rules for finding the drivetrain / mileage? Is it always the 1st and 3rd field?

Comment: @RoL : `getWord`is just printing the file to stdout, but don't store the lines of the file anywhere (except that `line` temporarily holds the most recent line being read). Shouldn't you process the individual lines somehow? You could use `split` to separate `line` on comma  into the individual pieces.

Comment: @RoL : In additon, just posting some function (method) is not that useful if you don't show how you intend to use (invoke) this function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [CSV (Comma Separated Value) file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). You can just split on the comma and take the fields.

```
# chomp: true removes the trailing newline
File.readlines(fileName, chomp: true).each do |line|
  (drivetrain,type,mileage,transmission) = line.split(',')
  puts drivetrain
  puts mileage
end
```

But CSV files can get more complex. For example, if there's a comma in a value it could be quoted. `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"`. To handle all the possibilities, use the [CSV class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to parse each line.

```
headers: [:drivetrain, :type, :mileage, :transmission]
CSV.foreach(fileName, headers: headers) do |row|
  puts row[:drivetrain]
  puts row[:mileage]
end
```

Comment: but what if for example, i have a file with[1- drivetrain,20km, mileage, transmission and 2-mileage, drivetrain, transmission,40km] and I need to find the km

Comment: for instance, we have these listings #km Kilometers followed by “km”
Type {Sedan, coupe, hatchback, station, SUV} and we need to find them from a text file [65101km, Sedan, Manual, Coupe,1100km]

Comment: @RoL Split them into fields, as above, and [find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) the one that [matches](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-match-3F) `km`. `mileage = fields.find { |field| field.match?(/\bkm\b) }`